# Help with the Validation Rule on Custom Object

Tags: validation

As per the standard functionality in Salesforce, when we hit **Enter** the record is saved automatically & we are directed to the detail page of the record. But I want to restrict the user from doing this(hit enter and save the record) for which I created a check box named 'I Agree to Terms & Conditions' & wrote a validation rule:

> I Agree to Terms & Conditions = False

Now the challenge is this works fine when the record is newly created but when we edit the record and hit enter the problem recurs.Can anybody please suggest how to overcome the issue?

Comment: remove `ISNEW()` from condition then your validation rule work for new and update of record..

Comment: Nope. It is not as simple as it seems. when the record is being edited & the check box is checked & by mistake someone hits enter without updating the record is saved again and the user is again required to Edit the record.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple enough. We just need to write a Workflow to Uncheck the check box field every time the record is created & edited.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can reset the value of a field when the record is loaded, during Edit. Since you are using a validation rule, when you try to update the value using a workflow field update that wont allow you to save the record for the validation rule condition written.

-- Hence forth the solution is you can add a disclaimer stating something like 'By Clicking on Save/ Enter XYZ etc.,'

Comment: The solution is tested & is working fine. :)

Comment: do u still have the validation rule in place..' I Agree to Terms & Conditions = False' ?

Comment: Yeah, The rule is very much active & working well.

Comment: Ok.. Now i got this.. This happens as per the order of execution...

"If the record was updated with workflow field updates, fires before update triggers and after update triggers one more time (and only one more time), in addition to standard validations. Custom validation rules, duplicate rules, and escalation rules are not run again."

-- Since the Workflow field update does not run the validation check again, this became a pass...

Comment: I appreciate what you explained above. :)